# Quotation Marks breaking Flask-pagination

Tags: python, get, flask, pagination, jinja2

In my Flask project, when quotation marks are passed in the search form (GET request) it is breaking Flask-paginate. Searches without quotes paginate fine. Am I missing a Flask-paginate setting or is there a way to escape or modify the quotation marks prior to sending the GET request?

I am using Flask 0.10.1 and Flask-paginate 0.3.0

Sample problematic URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?q="exact+phrase+search"
```

Generated Pagination URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?q=
```

Flask-paginate code in application.py

```
pagination = Pagination(page=<current page>, total=<total records>, record_name='results', per_page=<results per page>, bs_version=3)
```

Pagination code in Flask Results Template

```
{{ pagination.info }}
{{ pagination.links }}
```

Search Form code:

```
<form role="search" action="search" method="GET">
<input name="q" type="text"> 
<button type="submit" value="Send">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question but looks like this was just a bug in Flask-paginate 0.3.0. It is fixed in 0.3.1.
https://github.com/lixxu/flask-paginate/issues/26